# How to verify CRC-16 of a giant hex packet in C#

Tags: c#, crc

I'm receiving a hexadecimal packet with crc-16, so what i have to do is verify if this packet is corrupted or not, I'm doing it trying to calculate the receiver side of CRC. I have wrote some code that i will provide, but the result of it are meaningless values. So what am I doing wrong ?

I'm getting this hexadecimal packet from a wireless device, I have the code that generates the CRC that is attached to the packet. What I have to do is get the information that i need from this packet and store in a Data Base, but for now my problem is in CRC verify.

```
public class CrcReceiver
{
    private static String polynom = "A001";


    //ToBinary method
    public static string hexToBinary(String hexString)
    {
        String binary = "";
        for (int i = 0; i < hexString.Length; i++)
        {
            binary = binary + Convert.ToString(Convert.ToInt32(hexString.Substring(i, 1), 16), 2).PadLeft(4, '0');
        }
        binary = binary.TrimStart('0');
        return binary;
    }

    public static String CrcCheck(String pacote)//passing the packet as parameter
    {
        String binaryPolynom;//binary polynom
        String binaryPacket;//binary packet
        String substring;
        int inicio = 0;//determines the start of the substring
        String xorResult;
        int diferenca = 0;//gets the difference between xorResult and binaryPolynom           
        int xorResultLength;

        binaryPacket = hexToBinary(pacote);

        binaryPolynom = hexToBinary(polynom);

        int polyLength = binaryPolynom.Length;

        substring = binaryPacket.Substring(inicio, polyLength);

        inicio += polyLength;          

        while (inicio < binaryPacket.Length)
        {
            xorResult = xor(substring, binaryPolynom);
            xorResult = xorResult.TrimStart('0');
            xorResultLength = xorResult.Length;

            if(xorResultLength < polyLength)
            {
                if ((polyLength - xorResultLength) + inicio <= binaryPacket.Length)
                {
                    diferenca = polyLength - xorResultLength;                 
                    substring = binaryPacket.Substring(inicio, diferenca);
                    inicio += diferenca;
                    xorResult += substring;
                }
                else
                {
                    substring = binaryPacket.Substring(inicio, (binaryPacket.Length - inicio));
                    inicio += substring.Length;
                    xorResult += substring;
                }
            }

            substring = xorResult;   

        }

        return xor(substring, binaryPolynom);
    }


    //Xor method
    private static String xor(String Element1, String Element2)
    {
        String novaString = "";

        for(int i = 0; i < Element1.Length; i++)
        {
            if(Element1[i] != Element2[i])
            {
                novaString += '1';
            }
            else
            {
                novaString += '0';
            }
        }

        return novaString;
    }

}
```

CRC generation code

```
public sealed class CRC
{
    private readonly int _polynom;

    public static readonly CRC Default = new CRC(0xA001);

    public CRC(int polynom)
    {
        _polynom = polynom;
    }

    public int CalcCrc16(byte[] buffer)
    {
        return CalcCrc16(buffer, 0, buffer.Length, _polynom, 0);
    }

    public static int CalcCrc16(byte[] buffer, int offset, int bufLen, int polynom, int preset)
    {
        preset &= 0xFFFF;
        polynom &= 0xFFFF;

        var crc = preset;
        for (var i = 0; i < bufLen; i++)
        {
            var data = buffer[(i + offset) % buffer.Length] & 0xFF;
            crc ^= data;
            for (var j = 0; j < 8; j++)
            {
                if ((crc & 0x0001) != 0)
                {
                    crc = (crc >> 1) ^ polynom;
                }
                else
                {
                    crc = crc >> 1;
                }
            }
        }
        return crc & 0xFFFF;
    }
}
```

Comment: The generation of the CRC will read N-2 bytes of data and then add the two byte CRC-16.  To verify use same algorithm and use N bytes which should give results of 0x0000 or 0xFFFF depending on the CRC you are using.

Comment: what do you mean by 'N' ?

Comment: I think he means "the number of bytes you have received", i.e, the last two bytes are normally the CRC.

Comment: I tried the same algorithm (generation) calling the public int CalcCrc16(byte[] buffer) passing all my data as parameter after converted it to a byte array, and I still can't get 0x0000 or 0xFFFF as result. Should I edit the generation code to aply it to verification ? if yes, what should i edit ?

Comment: Absolutely wrong!!!  Doing a CRC on N-2 assumes the 21 remaining bytes are nulls (either 0's or 1's) so there are no exclusive ORs just shifting.

Comment: My problem is that i don know witch part o the generation CRC algorithm I have to change to apply it to verification. Because I dont understand this algorithm very well. I know that to verify the CRC is almost the same process to generate It, but I'm missing something.

Comment: As answered, you probably need to do everything in binary, treating the message as an array of 8 bit integers, not ascii characters.

Comment: @jdweng - I deleted my prior comment, since the CRC is not post complemented in the original question. I don't understand `doing a CRC on N-2 assumes ... 21 bytes`, in this case it's a padding of 16 bits of 0's. Some CRC algorithms post complement the CRC (the last step is `CRC = CRC^0xFFFF;`). If this CRC is appended to a N-2 byte message and then the CRC is calculated on the N byte messages, the result will be a constant, but non-zero value. Again, the CRC in this question does not do a post-complement, so the result should be 0x0000.

Comment: responding your first comment, as you can see, the first algorithm I was working with binary values but I did not get any relevant results, not even 0x0000 or a constant. If you know how to solve this, please help me.

Comment: I saw some exemples performing the same CRC algorithm on the data and just checking to see if it matches the supplied CRC. But I'm thinking, if is there's any possibility that the CRC bytes beeing corrupted ?

Comment: See webpage : http://www.sunshine2k.de/coding/javascript/crc/crc_js.html  There is link on bottom of page with "Understanding ......" which is very helpful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Start by converting your hex string to a byte array like this:

```
public static byte[] StringToByteArray(String hex)
{
  int NumberChars = hex.Length;
  byte[] bytes = new byte[NumberChars / 2];
  for (int i = 0; i < NumberChars; i += 2)
    bytes[i / 2] = Convert.ToByte(hex.Substring(i, 2), 16);
  return bytes;
}
```

Once it is a byte array then you can run it through your CRC code.

Comment: I saw some examples that use this kind of method but i don't really understand why. Thank you very much I'll try it.